# Deriving an estimate for $V_\mu 1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am currently reading Gilbarg and Trudinger's (and Jost's PDE textbook alongside). In P.159 of GT (also Lemma 10.2.4 in Jost's PDE book), they defined an operator $V_\mu $ on $L^1(\Omega)$ as follows:
$$V_\mu (f):=\int_\Omega |x-y|^{n(\mu-1)}f(y)~dy $$
for $0<\mu \leq 1$ then  showed that $V_\mu 1\leq \mu^{-1}\omega_n^{1-n}|\Omega|^\mu$ (here $|\Omega|$ means the measure of $\Omega$). They have provided the steps as follow:

Choose a $R>0$ so that $|\Omega|=|B_R(x)|=\omega_nR^n$, then

\begin{align}
V_\mu 1&=\int_\Omega |x-y|^{n(\mu-1)}~dy\\
&\leq \int_{B_R(x)} |x-y|^{n(\mu-1)}f(y)~dy\\
&=\color{red}{\mu^{-1}\omega_nR^{n\mu}}\\
&=\mu^{-1}\omega_n^{1-n}|\Omega|^\mu
\end{align}

This may seem like an easy question, but the third line really confuses me as I do not know how did they derive that equality. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me clarifying this equality!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keypoint is to prove that:
$$\int_{\Omega} |x-y|^{d\cdot(\mu-1)} dy \le \int_{B(x,R)} |x-y|^{d\cdot(\mu-1)} dy, $$ where $R$ is a ray such that $|B(x,R)|=|\Omega|=\omega_d\cdot R^d$.
Now you notice that
$$|\Omega\setminus (\Omega \cap B(x,R)|=
  |\Omega|-|\Omega \cap B(x,R)|=|B(x,R)|-|\Omega \cap B(x,R)|
=|B(x,R)-(\Omega\cap B(x,R))|;$$
moreover, these two inequalities hold
$$ |x-y|^{d\cdot(\mu-1)} \leq R^{d\cdot(\mu-1)} \text{for} \quad |x-y|\geq R,$$
and
$$ |x-y|^{d\cdot(\mu-1)} \geq R^{d\cdot(\mu-1)} \text{for} \quad |x-y|\leq R.$$
Finally, you decompose the integral as a sum
\begin{gather*}
\int _{\Omega } |x-y|^{d\cdot ( \mu -1)} dy=\int _{\Omega \setminus ( \Omega \cap B( x,R))} |x-y|^{d\cdot ( \mu -1)} dy+\int _{\Omega \cap B( x,R)} |x-y|^{d\cdot ( \mu -1)} dy\\
\leq R^{d\cdot ( \mu -1)} \cdot ( |\Omega |-|\Omega \cap B( x,R) |) +\int _{\Omega \cap B( x,R)} |x-y|^{d\cdot ( \mu -1)} dy\\
=R^{d\cdot ( \mu -1)} \cdot ( |B( x,R) |-|\Omega \cap B( x,R) |) +\int _{\Omega \cap B( x,R)} |x-y|^{d\cdot ( \mu -1)} dy\\
=\int _{B( x,R) \setminus \Omega \cap B( x,R)} R^{d( \mu -1)} \ dy+\int _{\Omega \cap B( x,R)} |x-y|^{d\cdot ( \mu -1)} dy\\
\leq \int _{B( x,R) \setminus \Omega \cap B( x,R)} |x-y|^{d\cdot ( \mu -1)} \ dy+\int _{\Omega \cap B( x,R)} |x-y|^{d\cdot ( \mu -1)} dy\\
=\int _{B( x,R)} |x-y|^{d\cdot ( \mu -1)} \ dy\
=\frac{1}{\mu}\cdot \omega_d \cdot R^{d\cdot\mu}=\frac{1}{\mu}\cdot \omega_{d}^{1-\mu}\cdot |\Omega|^{\mu}.
\end{gather*}
For the last two equalities I have used respectively the integration of a radial function in polar coordinates, and the definition of $R$.